# flash action script - is there a library to simulate human dancing?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to write a flash to simulate people dancing, but I think if I make all the animation by hand, it will be a huge work. So I am thinking if there is a library(or other things people has done previously) that I can make use of.

I can build the character, the foot, the arm and head etc. What I want is an algorithm to apply to the whole body to make it animate like a human, at least more smooth than a robot :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% on this but I'm guessing no such algorithm exists in flash. I think creating a reusable dancing algorithm would be very tricky. However if you end up creating it yourself I'd definitely wouldn't mind a look.